# Api-Platform: use validation_groups on DELETE action

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to prevent removal of an entity when it has some specific content.
So I added a validation rules, and it is working perfectly with a regular controler using a form validation.

```
//entity
    /**
     * @Assert\IsTrue(message="Delete not allowed", groups="delete")
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isDeleteAllowed(): bool
    {
        //some logic here...
        return false;
    }
```

Now I want to reuse the same logic for the api-platform part.
I have setup a validation group for the delete action of my entity

```
//entity
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "delete"={
 *              "validation_groups"={"delete"}
 *          }
 *     })
 */
```

However the api-platform DELETE action is skipping validation.
How can I enforce it?

For your information, I found the reason why it is not working in the api-platform source code where they deliberately ignore validation on DELETE action. So I opened a ticket to see if it can be fixed [Validation on DELETE action](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1928)

Comment: Please, show the entity code.

Comment: @Eugene The entire code of what? How having "more code" would help you answering this question?

Comment: @yivi just to check that answerer configured it right way.

Comment: Why not using a custom DataPersisters class and make your delete in remove() method  ?

Comment: @EugeneRuban the configuration is fine, I add a note to explain the root cause of the issue

Comment: @Hamham that may be a workaround but I guess would mean duplicating code logic that is currently used by my controller with regular form. And I'd rather stay DRY.
And correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand, DataPersisters arrive too late to throw nice validation exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution we used to solve this hard-coded behavior in ApiPlatform by reversing it in an event subscriber:

```
<?php
//src\EventSubscriber\DeleteValidationSubscriber.php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\ResourceClassNotFoundException;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Metadata\Resource\Factory\ResourceMetadataFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Util\RequestAttributesExtractor;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class DeleteValidationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $validator;
    private $resourceMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @param ValidatorInterface $validator
     * @param ResourceMetadataFactoryInterface $resourceMetadataFactory
     */
    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator, ResourceMetadataFactoryInterface $resourceMetadataFactory)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->resourceMetadataFactory = $resourceMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Validates data returned by the controller for DELETE action because api-platform is ignoring it
     *
     * @param ViewEvent $event
     * @throws ResourceClassNotFoundException
     */
    public function onKernelView(ViewEvent $event)
    {
        $controllerResult = $event->getControllerResult();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (
            $controllerResult instanceof Response
            || !$request->isMethod('DELETE')
            || $request->isMethodSafe()
            || !($attributes = RequestAttributesExtractor::extractAttributes($request))
            || !$attributes['receive']
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $resourceMetadata = $this->resourceMetadataFactory->create($attributes['resource_class']);

        $validationGroups = $resourceMetadata->getOperationAttribute($attributes, 'validation_groups', null, true);
        if (!is_null($validationGroups)) {
            $this->validator->validate($controllerResult, ['groups' => $validationGroups]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['onKernelView', 64],
        ];
    }
}
```

With that in place, validation is working as expected whenever "validation_groups" is explicitly defined on the "delete" item operation without other extra code.